# Informix doesn't find data which is not in select

Tags: sql, select, join, view, informix

This is a weird problem. We are running IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC4GE.

There is a simple view:

```
create view ifr_dwh_ktr as
   select *
   from ifr_dwh_ktr_head
   join ifr_dwh_ktr_pos on dwh_head_id = dwp_head_id and dwh_daten_art = dwp_daten_art
```

This query works:

```
select dwp_lh_prod, dwh_ktr_btype, zchg15_ben1
from ifr_dwh_ktr
 left outer join ifr_zchg15 on zchg15_zchg15 = dwp_lh_prod
where dwh_ktr_btype in ('P', 'S')
```

However if I do not have `dwh_ktr_btype` in the select-list there is no row returned:

```
select dwp_lh_prod, zchg15_ben1
from ifr_dwh_ktr
left outer join ifr_zchg15 on zchg15_zchg15 = dwp_lh_prod
where dwh_ktr_btype in ('P', 'S')
```

If I do not use the view and replace the `from` clause with the select from the view, it works!

```
select dwp_lh_prod, zchg15_ben1
from (select *
from ifr_dwh_ktr_head
join ifr_dwh_ktr_pos on dwh_head_id = dwp_head_id and dwh_daten_art = dwp_daten_art)
left outer join ifr_zchg15 on zchg15_zchg15 = dwp_lh_prod
where dwh_ktr_btype in ('P', 'S')
```

The query plan shows that the failing query is relying on a suspicious index (which does not exist)

```
Index Key Filters:  (dialog.ifr_dwh_ktr_head.dwh_ktr_btype IN ('P' , 'S' ))
```

the whole output is:

```
QUERY: (OPTIMIZATION TIMESTAMP: 01-22-2016 10:10:25)
------
select dwp_lh_prod, zchg15_ben1
from ifr_dwh_ktr
left outer join ifr_zchg15 on zchg15_zchg15 = dwp_lh_prod
where dwh_ktr_btype in ('P', 'S')

Estimated Cost: 2532
Estimated # of Rows Returned: 3787

          1) dialog.ifr_dwh_ktr_head: INDEX PATH

            (1) Index Name: dialog. 2773_2292
                Index Keys: dwh_daten_art dwh_head_id   (Key-Only)  (Serial, fragments: ALL)
                Index Key Filters:  (dialog.ifr_dwh_ktr_head.dwh_ktr_btype IN ('P' , 'S' ))

          2) dialog.ifr_dwh_ktr_pos: INDEX PATH

            (1) Index Name: dialog. 2774_2293
                Index Keys: dwp_daten_art dwp_head_id   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
                Lower Index Filter: (dialog.ifr_dwh_ktr_head.dwh_head_id = dialog.ifr_dwh_ktr_pos.dwp_head_id AND dialog.ifr_dwh_ktr_head.dwh_daten_art = dialog.ifr_dwh_ktr_pos.dwp_daten_art )

        ON-Filters:(dialog.ifr_dwh_ktr_head.dwh_head_id = dialog.ifr_dwh_ktr_pos.dwp_head_id AND dialog.ifr_dwh_ktr_head.dwh_daten_art = dialog.ifr_dwh_ktr_pos.dwp_daten_art )
        NESTED LOOP JOIN

      3) dialog.ifr_zchg15: INDEX PATH

        (1) Index Name: dialog.ifr_zchg15satz
            Index Keys: zchg15_zchg15   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
            Lower Index Filter: dialog.ifr_zchg15.zchg15_zchg15 = dialog.ifr_dwh_ktr_pos.dwp_lh_prod

    ON-Filters:dialog.ifr_zchg15.zchg15_zchg15 = dialog.ifr_dwh_ktr_pos.dwp_lh_prod
    NESTED LOOP JOIN(LEFT OUTER JOIN)



Query statistics:
-----------------

  Table map :
  ----------------------------
  Internal name     Table name
  ----------------------------
  t1                ifr_dwh_ktr_head
  t2                ifr_dwh_ktr_pos
  t3                ifr_zchg15
```

Does anyone have an idea what causes this weird behavior?

Here are the abbreviated structures of the tables in question:

```
CREATE TABLE
ifr_dwh_ktr_head
(
    dwh_daten_art CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    dwh_head_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    dwh_wert_art CHAR(1),
    dwh_rech_nr INTEGER,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (dwh_daten_art, dwh_head_id)
);

CREATE INDEX
idx_ifr_dwh_ktr_hktr
ON
ifr_dwh_ktr_head
(
    dwh_daten_art,
    dwh_ktr_nr
);
```

CREATE INDEX
    idx_ifr_dwh_ktr_hktrzu
    ON
    ifr_dwh_ktr_head
    (
        dwh_daten_art,
        dwh_zu_ktr
    );

```
CREATE INDEX
idx_ifr_dwh_ktr_hproj
ON
ifr_dwh_ktr_head
(
    dwh_daten_art,
    dwh_proj_nr,
    dwh_proj_vers
);

CREATE TABLE
ifr_dwh_ktr_pos
(
    dwp_daten_art CHAR(2),
    dwp_head_id INTEGER,
    dwp_satzart CHAR(5),
    dwp_vga CHAR(3),
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY (dwp_daten_art, dwp_head_id) REFERENCES ifr_dwh_ktr_head    (dwh_daten_art,
    dwh_head_id) ON
DELETE
    CASCADE
);

CREATE INDEX
idx_ifr_dwh_ktr_ppp
ON
ifr_dwh_ktr_pos
(
    dwp_lh_pseudo_p
);

CREATE TABLE
ifr_zchg15
(
    zchg15_zchg15 CHAR(5),
    zchg15_ben1 CHAR(30),
    ...
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
ifr_zchg15satz
ON
ifr_zchg15
(
    zchg15_zchg15
);
```

Comment: It would probably help if you could give an outline schema for the three tables.  We'd need just the main columns used in the queries, and maybe one extra column, for each table, with their types.  Primary key constraints, foreign key constraints and indexes might help too.  Some sample data that reproduces the problem would simplify life — maybe 5 rows per table.  On the face of it, the presence or absence of a column in the select-list should not change which rows are returned (with minor caveats about duplicate elimination which don't seem to apply here anyway).

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for your suggestion. I appended the abbreviated create statements for the tables at the end of my question.

Comment: Did you try creating the `view` without `select *`, and explicitly listing the columns you need?